# Why are name dependencies (WaR, WaW) in ILP architectures problematic?

Tags: parallel-processing, dependencies, instruction-set, vliw, superscalar

Assume the following two instructions are executed simultaneously:

```
addi $t0, $t1, 4
addi $t1, $t2, 4
```

It's an anti-dependence, or Write-after-Read. Assuming they are executed at the same time, wouldn't the first instruction still read the correct value before the second instruction writes back to `$t1`?

As for an output dependence, or Write-after-Write:

```
addi $t0, $t1, 4
addi $t0, $t2, 4
```

I can see why this is problematic, I can't imagine who would "win", if any. I mean we're speaking Instruction Level Parallelism, so theoretically I suppose there'd be a NOP before the second instruction can write to `$t0`? In which case I only see a problem if another instruction wants to read from $t0 before the second instruction writes to it again, and of course the "lost" cycle.

So really, my question is: why is Write-after-Read problematic? Is it because during the instruction decode, different addresses might be loaded into $t1?